# MVC Action Called multiple times after Link tag click inside Kendo UI grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi everyone I have a kendo UI grid used Inside an ASP.NET MVC 4 application inside a column defintion I encapsulated the template of that column inside a Link tag that references an MVC Action :

```
<a id="FundD" href="FundData/?CodeIsin=#= CodIsin #"><div data-dcr=#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DateCreationFond),"dd/MM/yyyy") #  data-code=#= CodIsin # data-comm = #= JSON.stringify(PaysCommercialisation) # id="libVm" class="title-fonds #: LIBELLEVM #" data-toggle="popover" ><span class="desc-fonds">#: LibClassificationNiv2 #</span>#: LIBELLEVM #</div></a>
```

Anyway when I click that column I must hit an Action that will return a certain view and pass a certain parameter to that action  , when i click the column   the action is called and the parameter is passed correctly but once the view is served the same action is being called over and over again many times automatically without the link column(Link) click.

Here is the action code:

```
public ActionResult FundData(OddoAmProduitFindRequest req, string CodeIsin)
        {
            OBAMVM obamvm = new OBAMVM();
            DispatchPageVM dispVM = new DispatchPageVM();
            ViewBag.Clist = from count in Const.OBAMCountries select count.Name;
            ViewBag.Llist = new List<string>();

                req = new OddoAmProduitFindRequest()
                {
                    CodLangue = SiteContext.Language(ControllerContext),
                    CodPaysCommercialisation = SiteContext.CodeCountry(ControllerContext),
                    ProfilInvestisseur = Int32.Parse(SiteContext.UserProfileId(ControllerContext)),
                    LibelleProduit = CodeIsin.ToString()

                };

                var FundDetails = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<HttpClient>().GetFundDetails(req).Values.FirstOrDefault();


                obamvm.ProduitResponse = FundDetails;
                obamvm.dispatchVM = dispVM;
                return View(obamvm);                    
        }
```

Does anyone know why the action is being called many times after The first click ??

Comment: is there some other code which can call it? Is an ajax action running simultaneously? Have you used your browser's developer tools to try and debug it?

Comment: Yes I tried that and there's no Ajax call thta uses thta action.

Comment: could there be something to do with the Kendo components where it automatically triggering a request? I don't know that toolset specifically. Either way the request must be coming from the browser somewhere. It should be possible to debug it with the tools, and see the requests in the browser's network logs.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the action in controller that is populating the gird and see if that is called every time too? I've had a similar situation where once the grid was getting refreshed it was calling the action to populate the grid.